# Sending function keys to a tn5250/telnet server

Tags: c#, sockets, ibm-midrange, terminal-emulator

I have a project that connects to an AS400 and communicates with a combination of plain text and what appear to be old ANSI escape codes. I have the project to the point where I can receive and send plain text, log in, and log out.

I have been told this thing communicates via the tn5250 protocol, however, other than the ANSI codes I am not seeing any unusual characters from the server.

I can send any plaintext to it just by writing to the socket directly. I must first encode it into a byte array.

- How do I send (i.e. what bytes are) function keys (F1-F12)?
- How do I send (i.e. what bytes are) *alternate* function keys (F13-F24)?
- How do I send (i.e. what bytes are) special keys (i.e. pagedown / rollup)?

  Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
  socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 23));
  socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Plaintext goes here"));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are connecting using VT emulation.

- [VTxxx key values by 5250 function](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaiw/rzaiwspecial.htm)
- [VT220 top-row function keys](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaiw/rzaiwtoprowfunctionkeys.htm)
- [VT100 and VT220 control character keywords](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaiw/rzaiwkeyboard.htm)

See the documentation for [VTxxx Telnet client sessions](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaiw/rzaiwmanagevtxxx.htm) for more information.

---

Note that there is a .NET database provider, as well as 5250 client emulation API's available. See [IBM i Access for Windows .NET provider](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaik/rzaikdotnetprovider.htm) and [IBM i Access for Windows : Programming](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaik/rzaikoverview.htm) for more information.